# Google Sheets autofill blank cells in one column with last non-blank cell above it

Tags: google-sheets-api, autofill

In Google Sheets, I have an imported sheet where every entry has a "package" number, but only the first package in each group has the "manifest" number for all of them, looking something like this:

```
      Col. A      Col. B
1     Manifest    Package
2     01234       43210
3                 43211
4                 43212
5     01235       43213
6                 43214
7                 43215
8                 43216
9                 43217
10    01236       43218
11                43219
```

I want column A2:A on another sheet to return A2:A on this reference sheet while auto-filling blank cells with the most recent non-blank value above it, so that I have a list containing a manifest number for each package. Also I want this in an arrayformula because I need to paste in updated data sets occasionally. I have tried several variations and combinations of `FILTER()`, `INDEX()`, `OFFSET()`, `VLOOKUP()`, `IF()`, and `QUERY()` with no success.

Thanks, -K

Comment: Not an array formula, but this would work if you're willing to past the formula down `=if(isblank(reference_sheet!A2),A1,reference_sheet!A2)`

Comment: David,
When I drag this formula down, it only fills in the first blank cell with the non-blank value above it. All blanks following read the blank cell above it and still return blank. Also, I would much prefer this in an array formula so that I don't need to manually drag the formula down further every time I update the reference sheet with a new one. Thanks, -K

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71646168/fill-empty-cells-with-the-same-value-as-previous-cell-in-google-sheet-array-for

Comment: And this: https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/fill-blank-cells-with-the-values-above/

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure this was figured out already but in case anyone is searching for a solution. I had the same issue and used the below formula where A is the column with missing data and C is the new column that fills with the data. This formula would go in C.

Hope this is helpful.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),IF(ISBLANK(A1),C1,A1),A2)
```

Comment: This doesn't address his need for it being on a separate sheet, nor does it work if he's going to paste in different size datasets, which is why he's wanting it to work with Array Formulas.