# Fill Empty Cells With The Same Value as Previous Cell in Google Sheet (Array Formula)

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, array-formulas

I have a list of data that can be seen in this example:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bRiupsmjfDRE9AgcM_5KJKAyxYKpQiMuyAGSoGaZYN0/edit?usp=sharing

1. Range A:B is the given data
2. Range D:E is the desired result

It is very easy to solve it without array formula. But Is there any array formula that can work it out? I need array formula so that i dont have to drag again and again when the data is added below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX({A:A, IF(A:A="",, VLOOKUP(ROW(B:B), 
 IF(B:B<>"", {ROW(B:B), B:B}), 2))})
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For column B, put in C1

```
=ArrayFormula(lookup(row(B:B),row(B:B)/if(B:B<>"",1,0),B:B))
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for that one! I had the pull-down `=if(B2<>"",B2,C1)` with input forced to start from `B2` and the inconvenience of the pull-down extra step prior to your solution. That fixed if very well. Be well!